# How can the magnetic $B$-field of a photon or light wave be directly compared to the electric $E$-field if the units are different? (Tesla vs. V/m)

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, dimensional-analysis, units

I know that the electric field of an electromagnetic wave has the strength (or intensity?) of the magnetic field times the speed if light $c$.

(E = B × c)...

But, the units are not quite the same (I did look at the two units in terms of base S.I. units... They are indeed similar, but not the same...)

So, how can they be directly compared in terms of their respective strengths?

Comment: Please note that the photon is involved in building up quantum mechancially the classical electromagnetic wave with E and B fields, it dos not have an E or B  field itself  as a point particle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle

Comment: @annav I took Kurt's phrase "the electric field of an electromagnetic wave" to mean that he is considering the $E$ and $B$ associated with a classical electromagnetic plane wave, not that the wave itself (or the underlying photons) have charge or source a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Teslas nor Volts are SI base units.

In terms of base SI units, $1{\ \rm T} = 1\ {\rm kg \cdot s^{-2} \cdot A^{-1}}$. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_(unit)). You can also verify this equation relatively quickly using $B=\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi R}$ and that fact that the force per unit length between two parallel wires separated by a distance $R$ is $\frac{F}{L}=\frac{\mu_0 I^2}{2\pi R}$.

Meanwhile, $1\ {\rm V} = 1\ {\rm kg \cdot m^2 \cdot s^{-3} \cdot A^{-1}}$ (again, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt)). You can verify this using the expression $V=U/Q$, where $U$ is potential energy and $Q$ is charge, as well as the normal SI units for energy.

Putting this together, where the notation $[x]$ means the units of $x$,
\begin{equation}
\left[\frac{E}{B}\right] = \frac{1\ {\rm V \cdot m^{-1}}}{1\ {\rm T}} = \frac{1\ {\rm kg \cdot m \cdot s^{-3} \cdot A^{-1}}}{1\ {\rm kg \cdot s^{-2} \cdot A^{-1}}} = 1\ {\rm m \cdot s^{-1}} = [c]
\end{equation}
Therefore, the equation $E=cB$ is dimensionally ok.